# Combining the values in two Java lists

Tags: java, list, filter, java-stream

The list I pulled through the database: (list1)

```
[
  {
    "id": 123, 
    "code": null,
    "subCode": null,
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 124, 
    "code": null,
    "subCode": null,
    "email": "test2@gmail.com"
  }
  ...
]
```

The list I got from the request: (response)

```
{
"code": "4d2042b5",
"result": [
  {
  "subCode": "d2042d2042",
  "email": "test@gmail.com"
  },
  {
  "subCode": "er3442rer",
  "email": "test2@gmail.com"
  }
 ...
]
}
```

*(sorry for my english)*
I have to combine the first list with the second list, edit and update the database.

The list I want to get:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123, 
    "code": "4d2042b5",
    "subCode": "d2042d2042",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 124, 
    "code": "4d2042b5",
    "subCode": "er3442rer",
    "email": "test2@gmail.com"
  }
  ...
]
```

How can i create this list?

The method I tried:

```
 list1.stream().filter(one -> response.result.stream()
                                .anyMatch(two -> two.getEmail().equals(one.getEmail())))
                .findAny().ifPresent(x-> {
            x.setCode(response.getCode());
            x.setsubCode(two.getSubCode);
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Please provide more context: how do you deserialize your json response and the contents of the POJO classes that you deserialize to.

Comment: start off with a normal for loop, once you know that it works functionally, then try to find an equivalent and then if you face any challenges, ask...people would find your questions much detailed and easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a look-up table (using a `Map`) to find `subCode` (value) based on the `email` (key):

```
Map<String, String> responseMap = response.getResult()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(obj -> obj.getEmail(), obj -> obj.getSubCode()));
```

> {test@gmail.com=d2042d2042, test2@gmail.com=er3442rer}

Now you have all set to be able to complete the object from the DB (let's call it `MyObject`). Here is no need of using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) as long as the setters are used:

```
final String code = response.getCode();
list1.forEach(myObject -> {
    final String subCode = responseMap.get(myObject.getEmail());
    myObject.setCode(response.getCode());
    myObject.setSubCode(subCode);
});
```

Note this solution assumes each email from `MyObject` can be found in the response (a collection of  "`obj`" taken from `response.getResult`).